# How do I sort SSRS Table Column Group on an value in decending order?

Tags: ssrs-2008

How do I set this GroupExpression to order in descending order:  =Fields!ID_Count.Value in descending order?

Answer (score 0):

To sort values in a group, including the details group, for a Tablix

```
1   On the design surface, click in the tablix data region to select it. The Grouping pane displays the row groups and column groups for the Tablix data region.
2   In the Row Groups pane, right-click the group name, and then click Edit Group.
3   In the Tablix Group dialog box, click Sort.
4   For each sort expression, follow these steps:
1   Click Add.
2   Type or select an expression by which to sort the data.
3   From the Order column drop-down list, choose the sort direction for each expression. A-Z sorts the expression in ascending order. Z-A sorts the expression in descending order.
5   Click OK.
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/sort-data-in-a-data-region-report-builder-and-ssrs